# A question on finitely generated $\mathbb{C}$-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, field-theory

Let $R$ be a finitely generated $\mathbb{C}$-algebra which is an integral domain of dimension $d$. I know that $R$ is of the form $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_n]/Q$ for some prime ideal $Q$. I am trying to understand the residue field of a localization $R_P$ at some maximal ideal $P$. I guess it should have a nice form since $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed snd $P$ is maximal, but I cannot see what is its form.

Comment: It’s not true, as $\mathbb{C}(t_1,\ldots,t_d)$ is a field, whereas $R_P$ is not (unless you localized at the zero ideal). Even then, in general, this field will be a *finite extension* of some $\mathbb{C}(t_1,\ldots,t_d)$. See eg the fraction field of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-1)$.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question since I was not sure of my guess anymore. I do not understand the first line of your comment though

Comment: @Mindlack The question is about the residue field of $R_P$, which is a field.

Comment: If $P$ is a maximal ideal, then $R/P=R_P/PR_P$ is a finite extension of $\Bbb C$ by the Nullstellensatz, hence $R/P=\Bbb C$ since $\Bbb C$ is algebraically closed

Comment: Thank you @leoli1. The isomorphism $R/P=R_P/PR_P$ is given by the fact that localizations commute with quotients?

Comment: Yes, and the fact that $R/P$ is already a field, i.e. $(R/P)_{\overline{P}}=R/P$.

Comment: Yes, I was wrong, I mis-read the question. Thank you @leoli1 for pointing it out.

Comment: Finitely generated implies that the maximal ideals have residue field $\Bbb{C}$, this is Zariski's lemma. @Mindlack